# How to get the TopLeft screen-coordinate of a PictureBox on a Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, coordinates, picturebox

I have a a `PictureBox` on my Windows Forms.

I am drawing a `Rectangle` on the `PictureBox`, with `ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame()`, and want to code some boundaries, so I am only drawing on the `PictureBox` and not the whole screen.

How do I find the screen-coordinates of the topleft point of the `PictureBox`?

**EDIT with solution**: Here's my solution, if anybody need to code some PictureBox boundaries.

```
                if (_isDragging) // If the mouse is being dragged, undraw and redraw the rectangle as the mouse moves.
                {
                    pictureBoxMap.Refresh();
                    ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(_theRectangleScreenCoords, BackColor, FrameStyle.Dashed); // Hide the previous rectangle by calling the DrawReversibleFrame method with the same parameters.

                    Point endPoint = ((Control)sender).PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                    var topLeftPictureBoxMap = pictureBoxMap.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
                    int width = endPoint.X - _startPointTheRectangleScreenCoords.X;
                    int height = endPoint.Y - _startPointTheRectangleScreenCoords.Y;

                    // limit rectangle in x-axis
                    var diff_x = pictureBoxMap.Width - (_startPointTheRectangleScreenCoords.X - topLeftPictureBoxMap.X);
                    var diff_x_2 = (pictureBoxMap.Width - (_startPointTheRectangleScreenCoords.X - topLeftPictureBoxMap.X)) - pictureBoxMap.Width;
                    if (width > diff_x)
                    {
                        width = diff_x;
                    }
                    else if(width < diff_x_2)
                    {
                        width = diff_x_2;
                    }

                    // limit rectangle i y-aksen
                    var diff_Y = pictureBoxMap.Height - (_startPointTheRectangleScreenCoords.Y - topLeftPictureBoxMap.Y);
                    var diff_Y_2 = (pictureBoxMap.Height - (_startPointTheRectangleScreenCoords.Y - topLeftPictureBoxMap.Y)) - pictureBoxMap.Height;

                    if (height > diff_Y)
                    {
                        height = diff_Y;
                    }
                    else if(height < diff_Y_2)
                    {
                        height = diff_Y_2;
                    }

                    _theRectangleScreenCoords = new Rectangle(
                        _startPointTheRectangleScreenCoords.X,
                        _startPointTheRectangleScreenCoords.Y,
                        width,
                        height);

                    ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(_theRectangleScreenCoords, Color.Red, FrameStyle.Dashed); // Draw the new rectangle by calling DrawReversibleFrame again.
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Control.PointToScreen( new Point(0, 0) )` where `Control` is your PictureBox.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen.aspx

Comment: Sure, take your time, I am not going anywhere.  C-:=

Comment: Follow the link you posted and note that the method takes a Point, not two integers.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that of all the random simular things I tryed :) Thanks alot Mike. +1

Comment: @radbyx sure, np. Another happy customer served. Besides the +1, don't forget to accept please.

Comment: @Hans Passant wh00ps, okay, my mistake due to being in a hurry to answer first!  C-:=

Comment: Sure buddy, I just had to wait 3 minutes after the 1+ ;/

Comment: Hans, your right. Mike you should edit your answer :) EDIT: well now I did it :)